# Linq group by and select most occuring item in sub group

Tags: c#, linq, partition, row-number

I have been struggling to write a linq query in c# for this scenario below, I have got a list with the structure

```
PostCode, Premise, Connectivity, Availability
XYZ 123,    1,       HIGH,         TRUE
XYZ 123,    2,       LOW,          TRUE
XYZ 123,    3,       LOW,          FALSE
ABC 234,    1,       HIGH,         FALSE
ABC 123,    2,       HIGH,         FALSE
```

I am trying to generate the below which I have done in SQL using ROW_NUMBER and partition but it's a challenge for me to achieve in c#. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
PostCode,  Connectivity, Availability
XYZ 123,         LOW,          TRUE
ABC 234,         HIGH,         FALSE
```

Comment: what is the logic of your output? perhaps you can share your SQL

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to show the logic you are using - why did `ABC 123` vanish from your answer? Why is `XYZ 123` shown as `Connectivity` `LOW` yet `Availability` `TRUE`? Can you show what you have attempted?

Comment: From your example I can't extract your requirement. Can you write it in words: given a sequence of (Postcode, Premise, ...), I want the subset of this sequence, containing those elements that ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It this what you are looking for :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<PostCode> postCodes = new List<PostCode>() {
            new PostCode() {postcode = "XYZ 123", premise = 1, connectivity = "HIGH", availability = "TRUE"},
                new PostCode() {postcode = "XYZ 123", premise = 2, connectivity = "LOW", availability = "TRUE"},
                new PostCode() {postcode = "XYZ 123", premise = 3, connectivity = "LOW", availability = "FALSE"},
                new PostCode() {postcode = "ABC 234", premise = 1, connectivity = "HIGH", availability = "FALSE"},
                new PostCode() {postcode = "ABC 123", premise = 2, connectivity = "HIGH", availability = "FALSE"}
            };

            var results = postCodes.GroupBy(x => x.postcode)
                .Select(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.premise).Select(z => new { item = z, count = z.Count() }).ToList())
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class PostCode
    {
        public string postcode {get; set;}
        public int premise { get; set; }
        public string connectivity { get; set; }
        public string availability { get; set; }

    }
```